# How can I use an array I created with php in a js function

Tags: javascript, php

I wrote a tool, that creates an array from a database (when the site is loaded) in php and would now like to use js functions to change the way this array is displayed in a table (different ranges, columns etc.).

How can I pass the php array to js, so I can use it in the js functions.

already tried this in the "script" section

```js
   <?php
        $js_data = json_encode($data);
        echo"var data = ".$js_data.";\n";
    ?>
    function loadCompleteTable(){

        table += '<table>';

        for(var row in data){
            table += '<tr>';
            for(var col in data[row]){
                table += '<td>';
                table += data[row][col];
                table += '</td>';
            }
            table += '</tr>';
        }

        table += '</table>';
        document.getElementById("tablePlaceholder").innerHTML = table;
    }
```

Comment: So you tried and what happened?

Comment: nothing at all ...

Comment: Open developers console, check errors.

Comment: @u_mulder found the first mistake, forgot "var table = ''; "

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array from `PHP` to `javascript` like this:

```
var js_array = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>');
```

Or if you prefer:

```
echo "var js_array = JSON.parse('".json_encode($php_array)."');";
```

I know you could just use:

```
var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>;
```

But i find it less reliable. Unfortunately, I can't find anything in the docs to prove what I am saying, but I had some troubles in the past, mostly `SyntaxError`, that was resolved by using `JSON.parse` instead of just echoing the array as `javascript` code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;

    function loadCompleteTable()
    {
           var table = '';
            table += '<table>';

            for(var row in data){
                table += '<tr>';
                for(var col in data[row]){
                    table += '<td>';
                    table += data[row][col];
                    table += '</td>';
                }
                table += '</tr>';
            }

            table += '</table>';
            document.getElementById("tablePlaceholder").innerHTML = table;
        }
```